# why gevent can't get the full pool of rabbitmq

Tags: python, rabbitmq, gevent

I want to get message from my rabbitmq,and then spawn greenlet using gevent to work on it.
my code is:

```
import pika
import gevent.monkey
gevent.monkey.patch_all()
import gevent
from gevent.pool import Pool
from gevent import Timeout
from meliae import scanner
import MySQLdb
import urllib2
from MySQLdb.cursors import SSCursor

db=MySQLdb.connect(host='125.221.225.12',user='root',passwd='young001',charset='utf8',db='delicious',use_unicode=True) 
cur = db.cursor()

p = Pool(300)
success_count = 0
fail_count = 0


connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='125.221.225.12'))
channel = connection.channel()
channel.queue_declare(queue='url_queue')

#logfile = file("log.txt",'aw',buffering=0)

def insert_into_avail(url):
    cur.execute("insert into avail_urls(url) values (%s)",url)
    db.commit()

def insert_into_fail(url):
    cur.execute("insert into fail_urls(url) values (%s)",url)
    db.commit()


class TooLong(Exception):
    pass

def down(url):
    global success_count
    global fail_count
    print 'the free pool is', p.free_count()
    try:
        with Timeout(30,TooLong):
            url_data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
            if url_data and url_data.getcode() ==200:
                #print 'url is ok'
                insert_into_avail(url)
                success_count = success_count+1
            else:
                print 'the code is ',url_data.getcode()
            #logfile.write(url)
            #print 'the pool is ', len(p)
            print 'success count is', success_count
    except:
        insert_into_fail(url)
        fail_count = fail_count+1
        #print 'the url is down',url
        #print 'the pool is ', len(p)
        print 'the fail_count is', fail_count


for method,properties,body in channel.consume('url_queue'):
    #print 'body is ',body
    channel.basic_ack(method.delivery_tag)
    scanner.dump_all_objects("dump.txt")
    p.spawn(down,body)
    #scanner.dump_all_objects("dump.txt")

    #print 'the pool is ', len(p)
    #logfile.write
p.join()
```

it works very slow,some output is following:

```
the fail_count is 30
the free pool is 295
the fail_count is 31
the free pool is 295
the fail_count is 32
the free pool is 295
the fail_count is 33
the free pool is 295
the fail_count is 34
the free pool is 295
the fail_count is 35
the free pool is 295
```

it only have about 5 greenlet in the pool,I want to get 300 greenlet in the pool,so the program will run fast.
what's wrong? how to debug it?because of rabbitmq,or gevent?or my code?
thx

**update:**when I comment "scanner.dump_all_objects("dump.txt")",it run in full pool,maybe because when I write the objects into file,it takes time,so it's very slow to get message from rabbitmq.

***but in my code,it seems to have a memory leak problem,the program takes hundreds M memory,so I want to print the all objects to find the memory leak problem? how to fix it?any better way?***

Comment: Notice that your code continuously time-outs; the fail count keeps going up. You should look into that and fix that first.

Comment: many urls is unreachable from my country,that's the time-outs come from.

Comment: writing to file is a blocking action and it definitely slows down your code. Your update helped me fix mine as well, i suggest you write an answer and mark it as the correct answer